# Sql query optimization to speed up SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: sql-server

Why this query takes 12 secs and it contains indexes perfectly.

Comment: If you look at the query plan, you'll most likely see clustered index scan -- and that should tell you that the perfect indexes are not being used.

Comment: I know you have them commented out but you should forget about using NOLOCK as performance booster. It can help with performance but it brings a lot of baggage with it. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ You also have top 5000 but no order by. This means you will not always get the same 5000 rows.

Comment: How selective is that filter on vch_EmailAddress? IE, how many rows on average it returns, and how many rows there is in the tblEmailAddress table in total?

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server will not (can not) use an index when your Where clause contains a Like statement such as yours. A scan must be done. This is because you've told SQL Server that you want all rows where vch_EmailAddress contains 'kala' anywhere in the email address. Therefore, a normal index will not get used. It must scan each row and evaluate each email address.

If you were to change your Where clause to something like this, an index would (potentially) get used.

```
where ea.vch_EmailAddress Like 'kala%'  OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: yes ur write...it takes 2 secs...requirement is string contains.contains in the sense we have to give like this %kala%

Comment: If that's the requirement then there isn't much you can do. A table scan or index scan will be required.

Comment: how we have to do for index scan...can explain briefly if possible

Comment: SQL Server determines whether a table scan or index scan is done. An index scan might only be slightly faster than a table scan. But the problem you have is that SQL Server must do a scan because of your Like statement. You want SQL Server to do a seek but it cannot.

Comment: An index scan is the operation SQL Server uses to find your String kala. SQL Server needs to scan your entire index because the wildcards (%) indicate that the text Kala could be anywhere inside the vch_EmailAddress column. This is a slow operation for SQL Server since it has to read through your entire column to find all matches

Comment: No change in timing also..takes 10 secs